# how to not create empty sessions for guest visitors

Tags: php, content-management-system, session-variables

I'm using a CMS-framework that initates session_start() upon page creation, however 90% of the site visitors are guests without the need for sessions, resulting in an awful lot of empty session-variables at server.

What's the best practice here? IF logged in, I need to know at an early level so I guess it means is both:

- Postpone session_start() until it's actually needed
- Keep the session_start() at an early stage, but make it conditional based on existance of cookie PHPSESS

Or is there a better fix, unknown to I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many large sites postpone the session initialization until it's actually needed, e.g. on cart pages and the user profile screen of each user.

In theory this isn't that complicated, if you were using a config file which would be required within all pages you could simply swap out a different config file for the pages that don't require any user recognition.

You're using a CMS-framework so perhaps you're somewhat limited within it. If you can differentiate the page creation process, using `session_start();` in one case and not in the other, then this shouldn't be that big of a deal. Keeping the logged in users logged on once returned to the other area of the system (the index file etc) would not work though. Of course you could be using `local_storage` to aid you with that but relying on JavaScript only isn't very reliable.

The easiest way would probably be to spit the system into two areas, one which doesn't use any sessions (index, other information files, etc) so the process behind those page creations would be different, i.e. not using sessions.

Perhaps you could have a session class like mentioned but it would most likely conflict with other previously outputs causing the sessions to fail, but if you could flush the other output then this could possibly work, but it's kind of a hack in my opinion and it wouldn't really solve the previously mentioned problem.

Have you considered changing the lifetime of the sessions? The default setting is 24 minutes but would reducing it to 15 change anything? Is 24 minutes really that big of a deal for you? Maybe the settings in your environment make them be even longer. Are there other aspects of the system that might be the actual performance issue? Are you hosting the system yourself or do those empty sessions really not matter?

Comment: You're right regarding session-lifetime. Same server hosting admin-tool with 12hrs lifetime, I probably add ajax-refresh and lower to default 20min. (The performance is not an issue, just ugly)

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting a lot of guest traffic without the need for sessions, then don't use it unless you absolutely need it. What I typically do is create a class for session, and add the session_start to the constructor of the class. Then, when I need sessions, I can simply call the session class within an underlying global.class.